# Estentiate SQL database with CSV file in Android App

Tags: android, sql, csv

I have a file with 100 records containing Name,phone,email.

The application should read this file and put it into SQL database in android app. Then I need to display names in a scrollable view with option to display full data on certain record.

I can't figure out the way to read this data from a file and add populating a database with it.

I assume that I need to read file records one by one until the end of the file and then insert into a Database using SQL statement. But How I read this using delimiters and where do I put this insert method? I assume it can be onCreate in a DataBaseHelper class?

Comment: Question is too broad for SO.... but to get you started, you will need to first read the csv file, use SQL queries to insert the data into a SQLite database, then you can use a CursorAdapter to display the data in a ListView.  Here's a tutorial on reading CSV files: http://javapapers.com/android/android-read-csv-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to read the file line by line and split the string by comma. Once you have the 3 strings (Name, phone and email), you can do the following:

```
// assuming you are using BufferedReader
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] parts = line.split(",");
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put("Name", parts[0]); // Assuming they are in the order you mentioned
   values.put("phone", parts[1]);
   values.put("email", parts[2]);
   // Insert the data into the database
   db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); // insert your table name
}
```

The above code snippet will iterate through the file, read it line by line, decompose each line and store the data in the database.

To answer the second part of your question - yes, you may have this inside the onCreate method of your database helper. But you can also have it elsewhere.

Don't forget to close any database connection that you may have.